# Yacc error: undefined reference to `line_num'

Tags: c, g++, yacc

I am assigned to implement a new programming language in lex and yacc. Below are some of my yacc code, it should print error and the line error occurs

```
//rest of the code
%%
#include "lex.yy.c"
extern int line_num;

main() {
  return yyparse();
}
void yyerror( char *s )
{   
    fprintf(stderr,"Syntax Error in line: %d\n%s\n",line_num, s);
}
```

The compiler gives the following error message:

```
/tmp/cclW8fn4.o: In function `yyerror':
y.tab.c:(.text+0x200f): undefined reference to `line_num'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

How to fix it?

Comment: `extern int line_num;` just declares `line_num` (says it exists somewhere and has type `int`). You need to define it somewhere.

Comment: If you want to use flex's built-in line counter, the variable is named `yylineno` and you need to add `%option yylineno` to your flex (`.l`) file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it was discussed in the comments `extern int line_num;`  just declares `line_num`, which has to exist in another file.

Therefore the problem was solved when `int line_num` was declared in the lex file:

```
%{
   int line_num = 1;    
%}
```